# SQL Performance Large Variable Varchar into Small Column

Tags: sql-server, performance, performance-tuning

Are there any performance issues placing larger varchar variable into small column? 
I did not see any performance difference in the execution plan. Just want to validate.

Example,

```
create table dbo.Product
(
    ProductId int identity(1,1),
    ProductName varchar(25),
    ProductDescription varchar(255),

    constraint pk_ProductId Primary Key (ProductId)
)
```

**Case 1 Large varchar(4000)**

```
declare @ProductNameVar varchar(4000),@ProductDescriptionVar varchar(4000)

set @ProductNameVar = 'Table'
set @ProductDescriptionVar ='manufactured , oak table, round edges..' 

INSERT INTO dbo.Product(ProductName, ProductDescription) 
VALUES (@ProductNameVar, @ProductDescriptionVar)
```

**Case 2 Small Varchars**

```
declare @ProductNameVar varchar(25),@ProductDescriptionVar varchar(255)

set @ProductNameVar = 'Table'
set @ProductDescriptionVar ='manufactured , oak table, round edges..' 

INSERT INTO dbo.Product(ProductName, ProductDescription) 
VALUES (@ProductNameVar, @ProductDescriptionVar)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is performance really your main concern here? Or are you just looking for an excuse to not bother making sure the parameter data types match the column data types? (This happens to be a common reason for just declaring everything as `nvarchar(max)`.)

Your parameters should absolutely match the underlying column types. If one changes, you change both.

Declaring larger data types for variables that will never hold that much data is probably wasteful, performance-wise, since memory has to be reserved in case you update the variable later. But this performance difference (if it even exists) is completely irrelevant, IMHO.

The reason? If someone puts 26 characters into the first variable, the insert will fail. And the error message is useless:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14
>   
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>   
> The statement has been terminated.

Imagine you have 10 columns of varying lengths, and 10 `varchar(4000)` parameters, and then you call this stored procedure 100 times, and get the error 20 times? Happy hunting!

Why invite errors that are preventable (or that can at least happen further up the chain)? You should be validating your input all the way up the stack:

- Make sure the form field can't be more than 25 characters (HTML supports this);
- make sure the client-side validation check that it is not more than 25 characters (JavaScript supports this);
- make sure the .NET data type is declared as 25 characters; and, for the love of all things you deem holy,
- make that parameter 25 characters.

Yes, that makes for more work when the length changes, but anything else is inexcusable IMHO.

Comment: yep, we have a lot of Entity Framework developers, their code is automatically setting everything to varchar(4000), I have to back anyway and rediscuss with team, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Aaron in comments section that it can cause your insert statements to fail if someone passes a values longer than your column length (I would call this a bug in your code).

Anyway, from performance's perspective, execution plan may look the same but SQL Server is having to do slightly more work when dealing with bigger data types as compare to smaller data types.

If you switched on IO and Time statistics on before running these two inserts, you will notice that the insert with bigger variables are taking slightly longer than the smaller/correct size variables.

**Insert with large variables**

```
declare @ProductNameVar varchar(4000),@ProductDescriptionVar varchar(4000)
set @ProductNameVar = 'Table'
set @ProductDescriptionVar ='manufactured , oak table, round edges..' 

INSERT INTO dbo.Product(ProductName, ProductDescription) 
VALUES (@ProductNameVar, @ProductDescriptionVar)
GO


SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
Table 'Product'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 406 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

**Insert with Smaller/Correct sized variables**

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;

declare @ProductNameVar varchar(25),@ProductDescriptionVar varchar(255)
set @ProductNameVar = 'Table'
set @ProductDescriptionVar ='manufactured , oak table, round edges..' 

INSERT INTO dbo.Product(ProductName, ProductDescription) 
VALUES (@ProductNameVar, @ProductDescriptionVar)
GO

SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
Table 'Product'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

Comment: thanks lot of these ORM software developers fill with varchar 4000, I will rediscuss data integrity later, first priority is performance , I am midlevel dba for company

Comment: I got nowhere near 406 ms on any of these. Most of the time they were zero, sometimes they were 3 or 4 ms, and half of those were for the smaller ones. I don't think you can make a conclusion about performance based on this single test.